# Splitting multi-dimensional array and grouping into associate array as same fileld in php

Tags: php

My array like this

```
$array = array(
  ['NAME[0]'=>'RAM','STD[0]'=>'4','SEC[0]'=>'A'],
  ['NAME[1]'=>'RAJ','STD[1]'=>'3','SEC[1]'=>'B'–]
);
```

I want to split like this

```
$name = array('NAME[0]'=> 'RAM',NAME[1]=>'RAJ');
$std = array('STD[0]'=> '4',STD[1]=>'3');
$name = array('SEC[0]'=> 'A',SEC[1]=>'B');
```

Comment: Please format the code as code, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: just I want to split this array as above mentioned. and please ignore enter code here

Comment: `$std=array('STD[0]'=> '4',NAME[1]=>'3');` looks strange?

Comment: It helps if you provide valid PHP code or valid JSON

Comment: I want to store this value in the DB  field. for example, if I was group name field in one variable like $name I insert this in DB name field

Comment: Right, but that first array you show us is not a valid php array, so how are you going to process it if it is not an array

Comment: And if you want to store all those occurances on a database I see no point in breaking them down to what you say you want. Just process each row one at a time onto the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with this

```
$array=array(
            array('NAME[0]'=>'RAM','STD[0]'=>'4','SEC[0]'=>'A'),
            array('NAME[1]'=>'RAJ','STD[1]'=>'3','SEC[1]'=>'B')
 );

$name = array();
$STD = array();
$SEC = array();

foreach($array as $vals) {    

      $i = 0;
      foreach($vals as $key => $value) { 

               if($i == 0){
                   $name[$key] = $value;
               }elseif($i == 1){
                   $STD[$key] = $value;
               }elseif($i ==2){
                   $SEC[$key] = $value;
               }                

            $i++;   
      }     
}

print_r($name);
print_r($STD);
print_r($SEC);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$arr = [
    array(
        'NAME' => 'RAM',
        'STD' => '4',
        'SEC' => 'A',
    ),
    array(
        'NAME' => 'RAJ',
        'STD' => '3',
        'SEC' => 'B',
    )
];
$names = [];
$stds = [];
$secs = [];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    array_push($names, array('NAME' => $value['NAME']));
    array_push($stds, array('STD' => $value['STD']));
    array_push($secs, array('SEC' => $value['SEC']));
}
```

Comment: this is just example I was getting count value dynamically not only 2. it's maybe 1 or 10.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, then how to I echo this.

Comment: Ram: How do you echo what?

Answer (score 0):

You can use  http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php

```
<?php

$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name');
print_r($first_names);
?>
```

will give you

```
Array
(
   [0] => John
   [1] => Sally
   [2] => Jane
   [3] => Peter
)
```

Or you can use exract() function

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp

Comment: It would have been a nicer answer if you had used the array provided by the OP